# missing values are considered lowest values in SAS?

Tags: sas

Why does the following piece of code in SAS give the output x=1?.
I am confused.

```
data strange;
x=.;
if x < 10 then  x=1;
    else if x >= 10 then x=2;
    else x=3;
run;
```

Comment: The simple answer is that "missing" (`x = .`) is the lowest number, hence less than 10.

Comment: When do you expect x to equal 3?

Comment: @Grayson when all else fails of course. The last else is the catch all else. I expected the output to be x=3. But it gives me x=1. Anyways Chris gave me the answer. Missing value is treated as the lowest number by SAS.

Comment: I think of missing like a null in an OO language.  Always check for missing first, and then proceed.

Comment: @ChrisJ actually the special missing value ( `x= ._`  )  is lower than ( `x = .` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in [Order of Missing Values](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000989180.htm) and in [SAS Operators In Expressions](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780367.htm#a000694997):

> Within SAS, a missing value for a numeric variable is smaller than all numbers; if you sort your data set by a numeric variable, observations with missing values for that variable appear first in the sorted data set. For numeric variables, you can compare special missing values with numbers and with each other.

As such, testing for 'less than' will include missing values.  You would need to add

```
if x < 10 and not missing(x) then x=1;
```

or similar.

There is however one case this is not true: in using the `ifn` (or `ifc`) functions.  Those support three valued logic:

```
y = ifc(x,'Nonzero','Zero','Missing');
```

However, that doesn't work in your case, as:

```
y = ifn(x<10,1,2,3);
```

will never evaluate to missing (since `x<10` evaluates to `true` for missing).